# (Oracle)Using asterisk in dataset

Tags: sql, oracle

Code 1 works as expected. It returns the value '2', if 'apple' or 'banana'.
My goal is to use the **asterisk '*'** in fruit column of my table to express that if all the other then 'apple' or 'banana', the value is '1' .
I want **Code 2 to return 1**. How to modify?

```
--Code 1: returns 2 as expected. ok
with datatable as (
select 'apple' fruit, 2 value from dual
union
select 'banana' ,     2 from dual
union
select   '*'    ,     1 from dual
) 
select value from datatable  where fruit = 'banana';
```

The problem is,

```
--Code 2: Expected result is 1
with datatable as (
select 'apple' fruit, 2 value from dual
union
select 'banana'     , 2 from dual
union
select '*'          , 1 from dual
) 
select value from datatable  where fruit = 'cherry';  --How to modify here?
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
select max(value) from datatable  where fruit = 'cherry' or fruit = '*';
```

Examples:

```
SQL> with datatable as (
  2  select 'apple' fruit, 2 value from dual
  3  union
  4  select 'banana'     , 2 from dual
  5  union
  6  select '*'          , 1 from dual
  7  )
  8  select max(value) from datatable  where fruit = 'cherry' or fruit = '*';

MAX(VALUE)
----------
         1

SQL> with datatable as (
  2  select 'apple' fruit, 2 value from dual
  3  union
  4  select 'banana'     , 2 from dual
  5  union
  6  select '*'          , 1 from dual
  7  )
  8  select max(value) from datatable  where fruit = 'banana' or fruit = '*';

MAX(VALUE)
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: @Soon . . . You can simplify the `where` condition to `fruit in ('cherry', '*')`.